How can I show some feedback from a Office.js Excel right-click command?
I have an Excel javascript add-in that includes some cell right-click actions, which can therefore be done when the add-in's task pane is not showing.
One of the actions should launch a pop-up dialog. But when running on the web, that dialog could be blocked by popup-blockers.
How/where can I show a message to the user in this case, asking them to allow the popup?
The right-click command runs in its own hidden browser window, so I can't show anything in the window, nor use window.alert() etc to show a message.
In the right-click situation, the task pane is likely not showing, so I can't pop up a message there (even though that's where Excel shows the 'promptBeforeOpen' box).
The Excel object model doesn't seem to expose any message / status / alert options.
So how can I show a message, asking the user to allow popups for my domain?

Please provide some more details. Is your add-in creating a custom context menu using ContextMenu markup in the manifest? Are you familiar with Office Dialog and with Handle popup blockers?

Yes, it’s the ‘Copy as List’ addin in Appsource. It adds uses ContextMenu and Office Dialog to get access to the clipboard to do a copy action.
So it shows a dialog every time you right-click. I had to switch off the ‘is it ok to show a dialog?’  Prompt as the prompt happens every time too.
In the ‘Handle popup blockers’ page it says “ Your code should catch this error and … display a message to the user advising that the add-in requires them to allow the dialog.”, but I can’t find any UI element that I can use for that message from a ContextMenu action.

I also found that “can I show a dialog” prompt got displayed in my Addins task pane, but that needn’t be visible when a ContextMenu action is occurring - so the user doesn’t see the prompt.
